# How to tell AWS glue my json is utf-8?

Tags: aws-glue

I'm trying to get an AWS Glue Crawler to create a table for a json file. My JSon file is utf-8 with BOM. It seems AWS Glue does not recognize the file as json (or anything at all in fact), so it creates an empty table definition. Plain text files do work (but of course they can't contain international characters properly).
Is there any way to tell Glue that a file is utf-8? I've tried setting the S3 metadata "Content-Type" to "application/json; charset=utf-8", but that doesn't help.

Comment: JSON is UTF-8 by definition. Try removing the BOM; proper UTF-8 should not need one and the Unicode consortium generally recommends against inserting a BOM. Otherwise, I'm guessing you are barking up the wrong tree here, or your data isn't *actually* UTF-8.

Comment: You're right, the BOM is the issue it seems. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe post a self-answer and eventually mark it as accepted (I think you have to wait a while before you can answer, and another while before you can accept, at your rep level).

Comment: Ok I will, I thought you might have wanted the rep ;)

Comment: tripleee the great altruist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out for AWS Glue json files cannot have a BOM. As triplee said in a comment, they are utf-8 by default. [RFC 8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-8) indeed says:

> 8.1.  Character Encoding
> JSON text exchanged between systems that are not part of a closed ecosystem MUST be encoded using UTF-8

and adds:

> Implementations MUST NOT add a byte order mark (U+FEFF) to the
> beginning of a networked-transmitted JSON text.  In the interests of
> interoperability, implementations that parse JSON texts MAY ignore
> the presence of a byte order mark rather than treating it as an
> error.

It would have been nice for AWS Glue to do that last bit, but they are not required to to so.